# how to call a servlet from a method, within the same class?

Tags: java, servlets, methods

How do i call a servlet from a method?
One method is started by a button and I want that method to start the servlet but, I'm having difficultly because it's a servlet??
I want setRc to call doGet which, in-turn, calls processRequest.

```
public class rc extends HttpServlet {


public void setRc(String rc) throws ServletException, IOException {
    rc test = new rc();
    test.doGet(null, null);
    this.rc = rc;
}

public String getRc() {
    return rc;
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("FROM doGet");
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
     //this is where the debugger quits...
    PrintWriterout = response.getWriter();
    processRequest(request, response);
    setRc(rc);
}

public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    name = request.getParameter("rc");
    IP = request.getRemoteAddr();
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\commands\\IPLog\\IP.txt");
    BufferedWriter txt = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    txt.write(IP);
    txt.close();
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\commands\\psexec \\\\" + IP + "  -s -i     C:\\Windows\\System32\\mstsc.exe /v:" + name);
}
```

}

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="info" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.WebTools.info" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="info" property="info" />
        <jsp:useBean id="hinv" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.WebTools.hinv" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="hinv" property="hinv" />
        <jsp:useBean id="rc" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.WebTools.rc" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="rc" property="rc" />
        <jsp:useBean id="remx" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.WebTools.remx" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="remx" property="remx" />
        <jsp:useBean id="SOne" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.WebTools.SOne" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="SOne" property="SOne" />

        <b><font color="blue">Please Enter your Full Name here:</font></b><br>
        <form name="frm" method="get" action="rc.java">
            <table border = "0">
                <tr align="left" valign="top">
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="top">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <%--   --%>     

        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://intranet/SITES/UBOX/SUPPORTUNITS/ITG/Pages/Default.aspx?cm_re_o=JPRr%20ZBFwCjCaB5%20WzM%20C%20mA55Byf%20JEbflCjCGa7"><img src="UBLogo.jpg" class ="ublogo" alt="UBLogo"/></a></td>
                    <td><strong>RDWeb</strong><a href="https://mpsc-dcs-util1/RDWeb/Pages/en-US/Desktops.aspx"><img src="RD.png" class ="rd" alt="UBLogo"/></a></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>



        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="2">Welcome to Web Tools</th><br>
            <th colspan="2">${UserDetails.displayName0}
                <br>${UserDetails.Full_User_Name0}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form name="info" action="index.jsp">
                    Enter the UB ID, User Name or Computer Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="info" />
                <input type="submit" value="OK" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><strong>Contact Details: </strong></td>
            <td><strong>Email: </strong><a href="mailto:${UserDetails.mail0}">${UserDetails.mail0}</a>
                <br><strong>IM: </strong><a href="im:<sip:${UserDetails.givenName0}.${UserDetails.sn0}@uboc.com>">${UserDetails.givenName0} ${UserDetails.sn0}</a>
                <br><strong>phone:</strong>${UserDetails.telephoneNumber0}              

                <br><span style="font-size:smaller; font-style:italic;">
                    <em>last login: ${UserDetails.Login_Date}</em></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>AD Site</strong></td>
            <td><strong>${UserDetails.AD_Site}</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Computer</strong></td>
            <td><strong>PC: ${UserDetails.Computer_Name}</strong>
                <br><strong>OS: ${UserDetails.Network_Operating_System0}</strong>
                <br><strong>IP: ${UserDetails.IP_Address}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form name="hinv" action="index.jsp" />
                Hardware Inventory:<input type="submit" value="${UserDetails.Computer_Name}" onsubmit=jsp:setProperty name="hinv"/>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="rc" action="index.jsp" />
                Remote Control:<input type="submit" value="${UserDetails.Computer_Name}" onsubmit=jsp:setProperty name="rc"/>
                </form>               
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="remx" action="index.jsp" />
                RemX_OKillX.exe:<input type="submit" value="${UserDetails.Computer_Name}" onsubmit=jsp:setProperty name="remx"/>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="SOne"  action="index.jsp" />
                5685-SourceOne.exe:<input type="submit" value="${UserDetails.Computer_Name}" onsubmit=jsp:setProperty name="SOne"/>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
                <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
        <!-- column data -->
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                    <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try: `response.sendRedirect("servlet");`

Comment: Just a hunch, but your doGet and processRequest methods should be in the rc class

Comment: In setRc, which i assume is the button callback, you dont have the request or response variables so you send null. in doGet since they are null you get a null reference exception where you commented that the debugger quits because your saying null.getWriter. This seems like a weird pattern. @niculare provides a good suggestion which will give your servlet what it needs. Otherwise think about hooking your button up to ajax with jquery so the doGet method gets correct parameters passed in, not nulls.

Comment: They are in the class - i removed some variables and accidentally left the "}" in...

Comment: I don't understand why you'd ever want to do this. In any case, calling request processing with neither a request not a response is meaningless.

Comment: @niculare - I'm not sure where I should put response.sendRedirect("servlet");

Comment: @ Steven Magana-Zook -  this seems weird bc becuse: the button holds the value of a pc.  that value goes into a commant line.  The purpose of doGet is to get the users IP and put it into the command line also.  this is a web app for our IT desk - it will open a remote control session on the IT service desk pc with the third partys pc as the parameter...

Comment: The methods of the `HttpServlet` class are invoked appropriately by the Servlet container itself. You should not be intersted in making a manual call by yourself. You're probably missing something about a Servlet - How it works.

Comment: I belive so too however - i am unable too...please, by all means, show me how you would do it?

Comment: @Patrick Bailey - How would you construct the request and the response objects then, on your own? If so, what is the advantage? Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? You should leave all of such stuff to the Servlet container itself.

Comment: @lion I am trying to use the information stored in rc as well as the IP address (that is available through httpServletRequest/responce) for a command line (for our IT dept - for an interneal web app) for this command:

Comment: Process d = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\commands\\psexec \\\\" + IP + " -s -i \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Configuration Manager Console\\AdminUI\\bin\\i386\\rc.exe\" 1 " + name);

Comment: therefor, I need the users IP address and the target pc name.  the tyarget pc name is stored in rc - which is the result of a previous sql query.  soo, IT person enters a customers name, sql query is performed, rc holds pc name and (by clicking the button) the IT service desk persons IP is captured.  Then click another button to perform a remote desktop connect on the IT persons desktop

Comment: Please edit the question with additional details. I don't see how/why you're trying to do it like this. Instead make an HTTP call from your cmdline app, like you're accessing a service. This still seems very odd.

Comment: @dave I see why this is odd.  It is odd because, when programming, you almost never perform commands on the server, local machine or a remote machine however, this is an app for our IT department (I'm a system administrator) and we need to be able to perform remote commands (by the click of a button) anyhow, this was/is a very challenging project bc, as you can see, it is not a normal way of programming, there is little documentation and few people with much incite on how to perform these actions through a web based app.

Comment: Additionally, the web is built to, one way or another, make this sort of thing very difficult but! joke is on you - internet! I did it!! hahaah!!!

Comment: I do that all the time--I just do it correctly.

Comment: @dave alright then, Dave, how do you do it correctly??

Comment: @PatrickBailey Oh, sorry, I thought I said. If you want to call a servlet from the command line, make an HTTP request and allow processing to occur normally rather than having to mock/stub everything in the world to make it "work". If your button is on an HTML form, there should be no need to do anything other than submitting the form/making a normal request and looking at request parameters/etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    RequestDispatcher reqDisp = new RequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    reqDisp.forward(request,response);
    or 
    reqDisp.forward(request,response);

or other way is
response.sendRedirect("/url to call");
```

### RequestDispatcher

forward method pass the control of the request to another servlet or jsp without telling anything about the request dispatch to the client browser. Therefore client browser don't know whether the returned resource is from an another servlet/jsp or not.

### sendRedirect

method stop further processing of the request and send http status code "301" and URL of the location to be redirected to the client browser in the response header. Server does not have control of this request after sending the redirect related HTTP header to the client browser. Client browser sees http status 301 and then it know it should send a new request to the url in "Location" http header which is set by server. and Client browser sends a new request to the new URL and it will be processed by the server as another normal request.

Therefore request dispatch happens completely in the server side.
But sendRedirect is handle through the client browser.